# Does What's Up Doc require a new contribution on Documentation?

Tags: support, winter-bash-2016

In order to gain the What's Up Doc hat, do I need to post a new contribution on Documentation for which I gain rep, or is it sufficient to gain rep from my existing posts/edits on Documentation?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I'm pretty sure that any rep gained from Documentation during Winter Bash gets you the badge.

Update: now confirmed, because I earned the hat by  sitting around and waiting for upvotes.

Comment: I agree. If you would have to contribute new material to the docs, it would say so.

Comment: Well, since you were correct and were the first to answer, your answer deserves to be accepted.

Comment: Hey, look, my first accepted answer that wasn't on my own question!

Answer (score 5):

Well, I can confirm now that you don't have to contribute new material to earn the hat.

I just got +1 rep from an old contribution to documentation and immediately got the hat!

[image]

Comment: Egoist hat FTW :P

Comment: @StephenLeppik What's FTW?

Comment: @Eran 'For the Win'